# Draw a specific graph with a branching.

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, trees

I want to draw the following graph:

> 1. it is a tree
> 2. it can have up to four children nodes
> 3. there should be no edges intersections

The part with which I struggle is the **3**. I am not sure how to avoid the intersections.

Whatever distance I will take between sibling nodes eventually an intersection will occur if I will add four children to each node enough times.

[image]

Is it possible to accomplish at all?

I am going to draw the graph programmatically.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "edges intersections" and why you think they are unavoidable.  It is well known that a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) is a [planar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) and so admits a planar drawing.  It sounds like you are wanting to draw a rooted tree where each parent vertex can have up to four children and you want to draw it in a way that avoids crossings.  In your image you draw a line between siblings... that should not be done in a tree.  The image you link is not a tree at all (*it has a cycle*).

Comment: You know how many nodes are potentially on each layer (assuming 4 "children"  from each node in the layer above). Just draw any nodes for that layer in their appropriate position along the line and join to their parent.

Comment: @JMoravitz, that line is not an edge it is just to show what I mean by distance between siblings. I am sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Joffan, do you mean just start drawing from the bottom given the data (set of nodes and edges) for the graph?

Comment: Or you could just do it from top down... Suppose for instance that we notate vertices as sequences of $A$'s, $B$'s, $C$'s and $D$'s, corresponding to the specific ancestry of the vertex.  For example, $AACB$ is the second child of $AAC$ who is the third child of $AA$ who is the first child of $A$.  For each generation, just write all $n$'th generational vertices in a line in alphabetical order.  No lines will ever cross in such a scenario (*though some will become heavily slanted*).

Comment: @JMoravitz, I think you can post it as an answer.